# Typescript generics infer type from parent

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to understand if there is a way to infer the type from another defined generic type:

```
export type DataTableRow<T> = {
  [Property in keyof T]?: T[Property];
};

interface DataTableProps {
  columns: DataTableColDef[];
  rows: DataTableRow[];
}
```

Is there a way to infer  from the DataTableRow?

Basically rows is a property on a React component. I would like to make the definition of the row to be type safe, for example:

```
interface RunRowDef {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  value: number;
}

const rows: DataTableRow<RunRowDef>[] = [
{id: 1, name: 'testing', value: 123}
]

...

<DataTable rows={rows} ...
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit further what you are trying to achieve? Your `DataTableRow` type looks a lot like [`Partial`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1569-L1571).

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve. If you replace `DataTableRow<~>[]` with `Partial<RunRowDef>[]` you will get the same output.

Comment: So the top portion is from a base component that doesn't know what the RunRowDef is. I want DataTableProps rows to infer row definition.

Comment: Please consider [edit]ing the code to be a self-contained [mre] that clearly demonstrates your issue without unrelated problems, when pasted as-is into a standalone IDE.  My IDE doesn't know what `DataTableColDef` is, nor is it clear what you want inferred where; it's possible you want [this](https://tsplay.dev/WPzvzN) but the surrounding example code is confusing.  Could you clarify?

Comment: Do you mean somethin like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NV7Qlm)